# How does it look to ask for a transfer to a new site?

Tags: relocation, internal-transfer, anxiety, burning-bridges

My family lives in an expensive area that has lost its luster for us in the past several years.  We want to move.  The group I work for has employees at other sites and some who work remotely.  I am tempted to ask if I can be transferred to one of these sites or work from home, which will then be several hundred miles away.  I don't know if they would allow it.  The contract with one of our major customers might require me to be located where I am.  So, I know, I'll ask!  But I am worried that management might not be able, or willing, to grant my request.  And then, if that is the case, I am worried further that someone will get the idea that they need to replace me with someone more enthusiastic about the position.  Maybe I'm worried over nothing?  I don't know.  Any advice on how to handle this?

Comment: Honestly, we can't tell you. Some companies, some people will go "sure, that's fine", other companies, other people might be "get out the door right now", most will be somewhere in the middle. Only _you_ can make the determination for where your company and you lie on that scale.

Comment: Does your company have an internal jobs board where you can see opportunities at other sites? Do you have an opposite number at one of the other sites who would like to swap?

Answer (score 1):

If you are a valued employee, then it is worthwhile to continue the idea of asking.

How do you know if you are a valued employee?  There is one test that clearly answers if you are valuable.  If you decided to quit the company (for whatever reason), would they attempt to retain you.  If the answer (from what you've seen) is that they let people go without extending them offers to stay, then odds are that's what will happen to you, and while you might be an appreciated employee, you're not valued for retention.

Assuming you are valued, is your value tied to your location?  If the answer is "yes" then you can devalue yourself by moving.  Should you know that you will have less value 100 miles away, you might reconsider if you don't want to change jobs.  Remember it is often not worthwhile to have an employer tell you what you already directly observe.

If you feel you are valuable 100 miles away and you are the kind of employee that they would retain.  Then the conditions exist which might make the arrangement possible.

Many people approach this from the wrong angle.  They think they can get the company to alter the company's needs to accommodate their personal needs.  This means that if your solution involves "they can just change X, Y, and Z; and, it will all work out!" then your solution is basically ignoring the company.  Focusing on the company's needs first will assure that your solution will have a chance of success with the company.

Rather than treating the company as an unknown entity, look at the company and see if what you are asking would obviously be denied for practical reasons.  Then look at the company and see if what you are asking would obviously be against corporate culture.  Then consider if they would spend the effort to accommodate this change based on how much they would wish to retain you.  That way you get some answers to your questions, instead of just a lot of questions (that nobody can answer because it requires the information you have that we lack).